# Copying content of one table's attribute to another table's attribute in a different database

Tags: mysql

I have a table named Crew which is like this

```
Crew(  
    ID int(11) NOT NULL UNIQUE,  #every crew member has a unique ID associated with
MovieID INT(11) NOT NULL, 
Name TEXT,
Position varchar(32),  #role of the person in the movie
role_id int(11);
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Worked_in) REFERENCES MOVIEDATABASE.Imdb(title) 
   )
```

and another table

```
 `cast_info` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `person_role_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `note` text,
   `nr_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `idx_pid` (`person_id`),
    KEY `idx_mid` (`movie_id`),
    KEY `idx_cid` (`person_role_id`),
    KEY `cast_info_role_id_exists` (`role_id`)
```

)
I want to copy the data entries of movie_id  in cast_info to MovieID in Crew and the person_id of cast_info corresponds with ID in Crew. Crew is of the database 'Mine' and role_type table is from a different database called 'imdb'. I have tried using insert ignore into like this but it gets stuck for a long time and doesn't finish executing.

```
 insert ignore into Crew(MovieID) select C1.movie_id from imdb.cast_info as      
 C1,imdb.cast_info as C2,Crew where C1.role_id!=C2.role_id AND Crew.ID=C1.person_id;
```

here is some info on cast_type table. the Crew table is mostly empty and only has the ID column filled so i am not posting it here

```
 +----+-----------+----------+----------------+------+----------+---------+
 | id | person_id | movie_id | person_role_id | note | nr_order | role_id |
 +----+-----------+----------+----------------+------+----------+---------+
 |  1 |         1 |  1005336 |              1 | NULL |     NULL |       1 |
 |  2 |         2 |  2248922 |              1 | NULL |       25 |       1 |
 |  3 |         2 |  2416848 |              2 | NULL |       22 |       1 |
 |  4 |         3 |  1923237 |           NULL | NULL |       12 |       1 |
 |  5 |         4 |  1745461 |              3 | NULL |     NULL |       1 |
 +----+-----------+----------+----------------+------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Give some sample data to make sense of the relationship there is between Crew and cast_info.

Comment: just added sample data

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do. In your attempted insert you try to insert something in Crew, that supposedly is already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this works out

Replace with your database name

```
update database1.Crew cr join database2.cast_info ci on cr.id=ci.person_id set cr.MovieID = ci.movie_id
```

And I am not clear why you specified about `role_type` table

Comment: It worked. thanks a lot. so you are basically making a left join here?

Comment: Nope. If nothing is specified by default MySQL will consider it as `INNER JOIN`